# Slow Wifi Adapter in Laptop

Tags: wifi, wireless, network-adapter, adapter

Hopefully this is the correct place to ask this question.

I have been struggling with a slow connection on mt Asus VivoBook since I got it a few months ago.
I have checked the drivers etc, and they all seem to be up-to-date.

The problem is, there is not Ethernet Port so I need to use wifi.

On a good day I might get 24mbps download but it can regularly be down as low as 4mbps.

Upload speed is generally 26mbps

On doing a search today, I seen someone else ask a question on TomsGuide and it turns out that they also have an Asus Vivobook

The network adapter that came with the laptop is `realtek 8821ce wireless lan 802.11ac pci-e nic`

Is there problems with this adapter?
Is there anything I can do to make it run faster?

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to Hardware Recommendations! The Realtek 8821ce is a reasonably modern Wi-Fi card, and should support much faster speeds. Could you provide more information on the Wi-Fi network you're connecting to? What model of wireless access point is being used? How far away from it are you? Are there any walls in the way? Are there other Wi-Fi networks in the area?